# How to register an item or block in minecraft 1.9

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Since the update has happened, forge have changed the way you register an item or block, 1.8 used to be GameRegistry.registerItem now it's GameRegistry.register but I can't get it right; any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll want to do something like this:

```
public static Item itemPickaxe;

public static final void init() {
    itemPickaxe = new ItemNewPickaxe().setRegistryName(ModInfo.MODID, "itemPickaxe");

    register(itemPickaxe);
}

private static final void register(Item i) {
    GameRegistry.register(i.setUnlocalizedName(i.getRegistryName().toString()));
}
```

This successfully registers the item, but I don't know about rendering yet.  I'm just learning this myself.

Source: http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/index.php?topic=38187.0